# Create and immediately update field using Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, update

You can create fields and once created, populate them with data using the Field Calculator. But can you do both at the same time using an expression? Or must you do it in 2 steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the attribute table, toggle layer editable (if not yet done) open the field calculator and check **Create a new field**, give it a type / name and use an expression to fill it with values based on existing attributes.

[image: Create a new field in the field calculator]

Comment: Wow, that simple...Thank you! Not sure if I'm allowed to ask a follow-up question or post another one but I will ask: If column_1 contains fields which has similar string (eg. field_1 = "Country: UK", field_2 = "Country: US", field_3 = "City: London"), is there an expression to update fields which ONLY contain part of the string - in this case "Country"?

Comment: Please open a new question for this. It will be easier to find for other people if it is not buried in the comments.