# Expression to create and populate column based on filtered fields

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I wanted to create a column and populate it with data based on data from other fields.

If **column_1** contains fields which has similar string (eg. field_1 = "Country: UK", field_2 = "Country: US", field_3 = "City: London"), is there an expression to update fields which ONLY contain part of the string - in this case "Country"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is connected to a related question I asked earlier: [Create and immediately update field using Field Calculator](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91840/create-and-immediately-update-field-using-field-calculator)

Following on from Matthias' answer, this expression allowed me to add a filter and populate **NewColumn** in just one step:

```
case when "column_1" ILIKE '%Country%' then 1
else 0
end
```